# How to find location of console error

Tags: html, css, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am getting a error in console. it goes away with a hard refresh in chrome but I do not know where it is coming from

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null     VM1701:1

Comment: Leave chrome set to break on all unhandled errors and the developer tools open. Then do what ever is needed to get this error to occur.

Comment: You'll need to use unminified sources too - otherwise your error won't be meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

If your using Chrome, open up the inspector and select the Sources tab.  From there, navigate to the file that the problem is originating from and set breakpoints in places where you suspect the problem might be by clicking the line numbers on the left side.  After setting a few breakpoints, refresh the page and the code will run and pause each time it reaches one of your breakpoints.  When it pauses you can also look and see what the code is doing at that point.  If it reached the breakpoint before the error then you know that's not where the error is.  From that you can work on narrowing down where your problems are.

[image]

Comment: problem is that file VM71:1 isn't anywhere? when I click on it it shows setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.zoom="100%";},100)